# Is it possible to get activity java file from an apk file?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to get the activity java file from an apk. previously I decompile the apk but could not find the actual activity java file.

Comment: if the code you are trying to decompile is not heavily obfuscated, you might have some luck with [Show Java](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.njlabs.showjava)

Answer (score 0):

When you decompile an apk, the code is not in actual format. Due to **proguard** rules and conventional rules names of activities and methods gets changed for security purposes(it contains some letters or numbers with your class and method names). So one will not be able to access an apk code in the readable format very easily.

Answer (score 0):

The decompiled apk will most likey be obfuscated and your are likely to get classes such as a,b, coming from the methods and classes e.tc, however you can run the app on a real device and use the command

```
adb shell dumpsys activity activities | grep mFocusedActivity
```

to give you details about the current app in focus. The last word after `/.` is the name of the class.